# Request change of address for non-root level domain name

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

Old site: http://www.tahlequah.k12.ok.us
New site: http://TahlequahSchools.org

Our new site is located at the `.org` domain above; however, we have to keep our old domain/site up until we're sure none of our employees are in need of anything from the old site. Currently when you perform a search for `tahlequah public schools`, Google's search results are still giving priority to the old site. As such, our visitors will go to the old site first (or only there) where they are receiving outdated information. I'd like to request a "change of address"; however, when I go to this section in my Google Webmaster tools > Configuration > Change of Address, I receive this message:

```
 Restricted to root level domains only
```

Is there a way for me to still request a change of address so that the search results are updated? Or is there a work-around for my situation of which I am unaware?

Comment: Has been asked a few times on here, no you can't use the address move as its for whole domains. Use a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell Google this in the Webmaster tools. The only way to do so is using 301 redirects from your old pages to the new ones. There was a Hangout on Google+ with John Mueller about this - in the end the move will take some time but Google will notice and understand it also without the hint the Google Webmaster tools.

German Hangout with John Mueller in January 2013: [Google+ Hangout](https://plus.google.com/u/0/113006028898915385825/posts/cboGsJjqvSD) (start at 00:25:40)

Comment: what's the point of the 'Change of Address' then?

Comment: Not sure about this, but I think the main purpose of the 'Change of Address' function is to transfer data from one domain to another.

Comment: It's to help a bit and make it a minimum faster. It might be a bit easier to implement and you do not have to care about all the 301 redirects. But in the end everything will work fine with redirects only as well. Let me find the Hangout on this ...